# How to best arrange students into different groups?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, divide

Problem:

We have 370 students in 31 groups, each student is interested in 1 subject (subject 1 to 6)

We have 4 classrooms, each classroom can accommodate fixed number of students with fixed number of subjects.

How can we best arrange those students into all classrooms so that they can all have their favourite subjects? If that's not possible, return the best option where each classroom accommodates the highest matching percentage.

Given that all students in the same group must go together.

Example:

Students:

```
{
  'G1': [ { '6': 9 }, 9 ],
  'G2': [ { '6': 7 }, 7 ],
  'G3': [ { '1': 1, '2': 1 }, 2 ],
  'G4': [ { '6': 4 }, 4 ],
  'G5': [ { '6': 2 }, 2 ],
  'G6': [ { '1': 1, '6': 5 }, 6 ],
  'G7': [ { '6': 3 }, 3 ],
  'G8': [ { '6': 2 }, 2 ],
  'G9': [ { '1': 2, '2': 1 }, 3 ],
  'G10': [ { '1': 2, '2': 6, '3': 3, '4': 2 }, 13 ],
  'G11': [ { '6': 13 }, 13 ],
  'G12': [ { '4': 1, '6': 8 }, 9 ],
  'G13': [ { '1': 5, '2': 5, '3': 12, '4': 6 }, 28 ],
  'G14': [ { '3': 9, '4': 3, '6': 8 }, 20 ],
  'G15': [ { '2': 4, '3': 10, '4': 2, '6': 3 }, 19 ],
  'G16': [ { '3': 9, '4': 8, '5': 1, '6': 5 }, 23 ],
  'G17': [ { '2': 2, '3': 3, '6': 19 }, 24 ],
  'G18': [ { '1': 2, '2': 1, '3': 3, '4': 11, '5': 2, '6': 2 }, 21 ],
  'G19': [ { '1': 2, '2': 4, '3': 6, '4': 4, '5': 1, '6': 3 }, 20 ],
  'G29': [ { '2': 3, '3': 13, '5': 1, '6': 6 }, 23 ],
  'G21': [ { '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 11, '4': 1, '6': 10 }, 25 ],
  'G22': [ { '3': 1, '6': 3 }, 4 ],
  'G23': [ { '3': 1, '4': 1 }, 2 ],
  'G24': [ { '6': 6 }, 6 ],
  'G25': [ { '2': 1 }, 1 ],
  'G26': [ { '2': 3, '3': 4, '4': 14, '5': 2, '6': 5 }, 28 ],
  'G27': [ { '1': 3, '2': 2, '3': 3, '5': 3, '6': 12 }, 23 ],
  'G28': [ { '6': 8 }, 8 ],
  'G29': [ { '2': 3, '3': 5, '4': 5, '5': 3, '6': 1 }, 17 ],
  'G30': [ { '2': 2, '3': 1, '6': 1 }, 4 ],
  'G31': [ { '6': 1 }, 1 ]
}
```

Classrooms:

```
{
      '1B': [ { '3': 9, '4': 19, '5': 1, '6': 71 }, 100 ],
      '1A': [ { '1': 11, '2': 19, '3': 33, '4': 1, '6': 16 }, 80 ],
      '2B': [ { '2': 3, '3': 14, '4': 38, '5': 12, '6': 43 }, 110 ],
      '2A': [ { '1': 8, '2': 18, '3': 38, '6': 16 }, 80 ]
}
```

Brute force seems not possible because the real problem can contain up to 1500 students.

Comment: why is this tagged with javascript?

Comment: @Zer0 sorry just a preference language, if the coding is in Javascript that would be nice, but I am just looking for some algorithms

Comment: @DavidThomas oh sorry it's not a homework question. I was just trying to re-phrase it so that it's easier to explain (real problem completely different)

I was thinking of using subSetSum to check all the possible combinations that adds-up to the first classroom, then in those combination I can check whether it satisfies the "subject" requirement, if it passes; slice that combination from the array and continue to subSetSum the remaining for 2nd classroom and so on.

But this brute force approach seems very time-consuming

Comment: You have duplicate G29.

Comment: @aropan oh sorry should be G20

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use [simulated annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) to find some optimal solution and use [iou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) for metric.

I try to do it and not a perfect solution (mean IOU is equal to `0.8079440721`):

```
{'G1': '2B', 'G2': '1B', 'G3': '1A', 'G4': '1B', 'G5': '1B', 'G6': '2B', 'G7': '1B', 'G8': '1B', 'G9': '2A', 'G10': '1A', 'G11': '1B', 'G12': '1B', 'G13': '2A', 'G14': '1A', 'G15': '1A', 'G16': '1B', 'G17': '1B', 'G18': '2B', 'G19': '1A', 'G20': '2A', 'G21': '2A', 'G22': '2B', 'G23': '1A', 'G24': '2B', 'G25': '2A', 'G26': '2B', 'G27': '2B', 'G28': '1B', 'G29': '2B', 'G30': '1A', 'G31': '1A'}
```

```
1B {'2': 2, '3': 12, '4': 9, '5': 1, '6': 71}
1A {'1': 5, '2': 17, '3': 30, '4': 12, '5': 1, '6': 16}
2B {'1': 6, '2': 9, '3': 16, '4': 30, '5': 10, '6': 43}
2A {'1': 8, '2': 12, '3': 36, '4': 7, '5': 1, '6': 16}
```

```
iou for 1B = 0.8571428571428571
iou for 1A = 0.75
iou for 2B = 0.8064516129032258
iou for 2A = 0.8181818181818182
```

Comment: thanks man! I've been trying to use SA to solve this and it actually works. I have a modified cost function i/o iou though (since I have different weights for different element).
Thanks again, really helped me a lot